# Android Clipping some part of Viewgroup

Tags: android

I have a Viewgroup(layout) in which I want to hide (or) clip some part on the left side. Clipping size may be around 100-150 dp, If i have a view i can do it by setVisibility method which hides the view entirely, I just need to hide specific part of my Viewgroup. Can somebody suggest me an idea on how to achieve this thing.